# Select a row based on the contents of a cell with xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I have a table that consists of multiple rows that each contain 5 cells, like this:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>statusText</td>
    <td><a>linkText</a></td>
    <td>editButton</td>
</tr>
```

The 123456 could be any string of random letters and numbers.  I want to be able to select a link based on the contents of the second cell in the table.  I've been trying something like this:

```
//tr[contains(td, '123456')]
```

to get me to the cell, but it either returns every row or nothing, depending on how I tweak the xpath.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and one possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying something like this:
>
> ```
> //tr[contains(td, '123456')]
> ```
>
> to get me to the cell, but it either
>   returns every row or nothing,
>   depending on how I tweak the xpath

**You get what you asked for**. The above XPath expression selects any  `tr` element (*row*) in the document that has (at least one) `td` child whose string value *contains* '123456'.

**But you want**:

```
//tr/td[text() = '123456']
```

this selects every `td` element (*cell*) in the document, that has a text node child, whose string value *is* '123456'.

There can be different variations, depending on whether a `td` may have more than one text nodes and on whether the white space in a text node should be normalized, but the question doesn't provide any information if any of these apply in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd research something like `//tr[string(td[2]) = '123456']`. If this does not work, I'd look up XPath axes.